# Spring Boot: How to create an Entity with a composite key

Tags: java, spring-boot, orm, hibernate-mapping

I was creating my classes for a project using a chart for practice purposes until I stumbled upon this `order_items`:

[image: part of the chart I'm using]

I had no problem creating an Entity like `Orders` or `Products` because I knew that for Orders I just had to do something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Integer orderId;
    // rest of the code...
}
```

And for for `Products` something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer productId;
    // rest of the code...
}
```

But the table `order_items` has the variables `order_id` and `item_id`, does that count as a composite key? If that is the case, how should those variables look in my `OrderItems` class?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
public class OrderItems {
    
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Integer orderId;
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private Integer itemId;
    // rest of the code...
}
```

I've checked different questions and they mention using `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddableId` for composite keys, but I'd like to confirm first if that is what I should do in this situation, unless it's not the case, maybe there are more approaches.

I'd really appreciate opinions and/or any article related to this, thank your for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can use  `@EmbeddableId`.

Here is example :

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class OrderItemsPK  implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(insertable = false, unique = false, updatable = false, nullable = false,name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;

    @Column(insertable = false, unique = false, updatable = false, nullable = false,name = "products_id")
    private Long productsId;
}
```

And the Order Items Class.

```
@Entity
public class OrderItems {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderItemsPK id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "products_id", nullable = false, unique = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "products_id")
    private Products products;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "orders_id", nullable = false, unique = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "orders_id")
    private Order order;

    private Long itemId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll use the `@Embeddable` then, your example does give me a partial idea of how to do the composite key thing, but I won't mark it as answer because it doesn't refer to how `item_id` should look within `OrderItems`.